# Modificacion-Error en la creacion de una instancia con jsf-spring-hibernate-mysql

Tags: java, jsf, spring, hibernate

Ya hice esta pregunta anteriormente pero ahora me da otro error producto de un cambio. Soy principiante en esto de Spring-Hibernate(se lo esencial). He creado en Netbean un login con hibernate (anotaciones) y acceso a MySql pero cuando le incorporé Spring y sus anotaciones me atore, ya en el primer intento no lo logre. 
Por orden he creado los paquetes clases, bean, bo, bo.Spring, dao, dao.Spring con el siguiente código según corresponde:

Este es el codigo de la pagina JSF

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Acceso a Sicoca</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/estiloLogin.css"></link>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>Bienvenidos a SIPRELI</h1>
        <h:form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h:outputText value="Usuario"/>   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <h:inputText id="usuario" value="#{usuarioBean.elUsuario.usuario}" 
                                     rendered="true" label="Error"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h:outputText value="Password"/>   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{usuarioBean.elUsuario.contrasena}" 
                                       rendered="true" label="Error"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <h:commandButton value="Entrar" action="#{usuarioBean.entrar(usuarioBean.elUsuario)}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Este es el codigo del UsuarioBean

```
package beans;
import clases.UsuarioLogin;
import bo.spring.IUsuarioBo;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;`

@Component //Cambio de ManagedBean y eliminacion de Sessionscoped por Component
public class UsuarioBean implements Serializable{
    private UsuarioLogin elUsuario;
    private IUsuarioBo usuarioBo;
    private boolean agregado;
    private FacesMessage msj;
    private List<UsuarioLogin> listaUsuario;
    private HtmlDataTable tableUsuario;`

   public UsuarioBean (){
        elUsuario = new UsuarioLogin();
        // usuarioBo = new UsuarioBo(); // Solo para pruebas y simulaciones
    }

   public String entrar(UsuarioLogin elUsuario){
        boolean existe;
        existe = usuarioBo.entrar(elUsuario); 
        if (existe) {
            return "index.xhtml";
        } else{
            return "";
        }
    }
```

En el paquete de bo

```
package bo;
import clases.UsuarioLogin;
import bo.spring.IUsuarioBo;
import dao.spring.IUsuarioDao;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service
public class UsuarioBo implements IUsuarioBo {
 @Autowired
    private IUsuarioDao usuarioDao;
 @Override
    public boolean entrar(UsuarioLogin elUsuario) {
        return usuarioDao.entrar(elUsuario);
    }
    public void setUsuarioDao(IUsuarioDao usuarioDao) {
        this.usuarioDao = usuarioDao;
    }
}
```

El error que me produce es el siguiente

> Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /acceso.xhtml @19,69
>   value="#{usuarioBean.elUsuario.usuario}": Target Unreachable,
>   identifier 'usuarioBean' resolved to null

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan dar se los agradezco desde ya.

JC

Comment: Por qué le quitaste el ManagedBean y SessionScoped y le agregaste solo el Component?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es por que quitaste el ManagedBean  y lo anotaste como un @Component, si lo que intentaste hace es inyectar tu  servicio UsuarioBo en el managedBean debio ser de la siguiente forma:

`@ManagedProperty("#{iUsuarioBo}")
    private IUsuarioBo iUsuarioBo ;`

Comment: Gerardo, anteriormente lo tenia con `@ManagedBean` y el `@SessionScoped` y me reconocía el bean sin problema pero cuando plantie la pregunta por primera vez me dijeron que estaba mezclando las anotaciones y que el bean estaba siendo administrado por JSF y no por Spring, (y que producia el error de no se creaba la instancia de usuarioBo) entonces me recomendaron hacer el cambio a `@Component` pero me produjo el error que coloque en esta consulta. Si tienes una idea de como resolverlo me favor me comentas en detalle ya que Spring me esta haciendo la vida imposible. Gracias